# generic type-based function to sum numbers based on their types

Tags: scala

Suppose x and y are of the same type and can be either `Boolean`, `Int`, or `Double`. Here is the function I want to write:

```
f(x, y) = 
   - if x == Boolean ==>   !x 
   - if x == Integer or x == Double ==> x+ y
```

One way of doing this can be the following. I was wondering if anyone has a better ideas on this.

```
def fun[T](x: T, y: T): T { 
   x match { 
       case xP: Boolean => !xP 
       case xP: Double => y match { case yP: Double =>  xP + yP }
       case xP: Int => y match { case yP: Int =>  xP + yP }
   }
}
```

The reason I am not happy with this is that `x` and `y` have the same type.  I shouldn't need two `match-case`s; right?

Two other things:

- Is it enough to just set `[T <: Int, Double, Boolean]`  in order to restrict the type to only three types?
- The output type needs to be again `T`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is precisely the kind of problem that type classes are designed to solve. In your case you could write something like this:

```
trait Add[A] {
  def apply(a: A, b: A): A
}

object Add {
  implicit val booleanAdd: Add[Boolean] = new Add[Boolean] {
    def apply(a: Boolean, b: Boolean): Boolean = !a
  }

  implicit def numericAdd[A: Numeric]: Add[A] = new Add[A] {
    def apply(a: A, b: A): A = implicitly[Numeric[A]].plus(a, b)
  }
}
```

A value of type `Add[X]` describes how to add two values of type `X`. You put implicit "instances" of type `Add[X]` in scope for every type `X` that you want to be able to perform this operation on. In this case I've provided instances for `Boolean` and any type that has an instance of `scala.math.Numeric` (a type class that's provided by the standard library). If you only wanted instances for `Int` and `Double`, you could simply leave out `numericAdd` and write your own `Add[Int]` and `Add[Double]` instances.

You'd write your `fun` like this:

```
def fun[T: Add](x: T, y: T) = implicitly[Add[T]].apply(x, y)
```

And use it like this:

```
scala> fun(true, false)
res0: Boolean = false

scala> fun(1, 2)
res1: Int = 3

scala> fun(0.01, 1.01)
res2: Double = 1.02
```

This has the very significant advantage of not blowing up at runtime on types that you haven't defined the operation for. Instead of crashing your program with a `MatchError` exception when you pass e.g. two strings to `fun`, you get a nice compilation failure:

```
scala> fun("a", "b")
<console>:14: error: could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type Add[String]
       fun("a", "b")
          ^
```

In general "type case" matching (i.e. matches that look like `case x: X => ...`) are a bad idea in Scala, and there's almost always a better solution. Often it'll involve type classes.

Comment: One other point: there's no (reasonably straightforward) way to accomplish a type constraint like `[T <: Int, Double, Boolean]`. You can do something similar but it involves using substantial more complex type classes, and the simpler, less generic version above is usually preferable.

Answer (score 4):

If you want a generic function for summing numbers, you can make a trait `Summable[A]` with implicit conversions from the numbers you want to `Summable`. These conversions can be implicit methods or they can be methods in implicit objects, latter being shown below.

```
trait Summable[A] {
  def +(a: A, b: A): A
}

object Summable {
  implicit object SummableBoolean extends Summable[Boolean] {
    override def +(a: Boolean, b: Boolean) = !a
  }
  implicit object SummableInt extends Summable[Int] {
    override def +(a: Int, b: Int) = a + b
  }
  implicit object SummableDouble extends Summable[Double] {
    override def +(a: Double, b: Double) = a + b
  }
}

def fun[A](a: A, b: A)(implicit ev: Summable[A]) =
  ev.+(a, b)

val res1 = fun(true, true) // returns false
val res2 = fun(1, 3) // returns 4
val res3 = fun(1.5, 4.3) // returns "5.8"
```

This is called a type class pattern. I included the boolean case because you asked for it, but I strongly believe that it has no place in a function which sums elements. One nice rule to follow is to have each function do one thing and one thing only. Then you can easily compose them into bigger functions. Inverting boolean has no place in a function that sums its arguments.

Comment: You beat me by a minute, but I'll leave my answer because it goes into a little more detail. I'd also suggest in general not using objects for instances (`val` or `def` introduces fewer types into your public API) and not using `override` when you're not overriding something. I also tend to avoid using `+` as a method name, since `+` is somewhat magical in Scala, but that's more a matter of taste.

Comment: I also don't normally use + but for some reason I put it here :) I disagree with override, it's a matter of style and I like putting it when implementing abstract members because it gives me safety that I really am implementing something abstract (e.g. if you misspell the method name without abstract you can't know). First time I've heard the argument against using implicit objects; I'll keep that in mind.

Comment: Hmm, I have exactly the opposite motivation for avoiding `override`. If I forget to implement an abstract method, the compiler will complain anyway. If I accidentally implement a non-abstract method (without intending to override it), leaving off `override` by default means I also get a nice error.

Comment: To be honest, I'm kind of used to it by now. Can't argue that my viewpoint is correct any more than yours. As long as Odersky and the rest of the gang agree that it's a matter of personal preference with no standardized convention, I feel that there's no "wrong answer" really (as long as you're consistent throughout your own code)

Answer (score -1):

First of all, your example is syntactically wrong (missing `case` in `match`). A simple and shorter way I can figure now is something like this:

```
def fun[T <: AnyVal](x: T, y: T) = {
  x match {
    case xP: Boolean => !xP
    case xP: Double => xP + y.asInstanceOf[Double]
    case xP: Int => xP + y.asInstanceOf[Int]
  }
}

fun(1, 2)            // res0: AnyVal = 3
fun(2.5, 2.6)        // res1: AnyVal = 5.1
fun(true, false)     // res2: AnyVal = false
```

Comment: What happens if you change the signature to `def fun[T <: AnyVal](x: T, y: T): T = .. `

Comment: This has at least two problems: it crashes at runtime on `Long`, `Float`, etc., but it also breaks in more painful, less obvious ways if someday you decide to extend it to generic types.

Comment: Actually nothing, you just make explicit the return type to `T`