# What is a better way to make a generic method that sums a List of any numeric primitive?

Tags: scala, generics

Considering I'll recieve a List[List[AnyVal]], I want to return a single List that each of it's elements is the sum of the inner list in that position.

I've made the code below but I'm almost sure there is a much better solution, how should I deal with this problem?

```
    def sumGenList(value: List[List[AnyVal]]) = {
        value.map(x =>
            x.head match {
                case d if d.isInstanceOf[Double] => x.map(y => y.toString.toDouble).sum
                case f if f.isInstanceOf[Float] => x.map(y => y.toString.toFloat).sum
                case l if l.isInstanceOf[Long] => x.map(y => y.toString.toLong).sum
                case i if i.isInstanceOf[Int] => x.map(y => y.toString.toInt).sum

                case _ => println("Error: NaN List")
            }
        )
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [generic type-based function to sum numbers based on their types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35384185/generic-type-based-function-to-sum-numbers-based-on-their-types)

Comment: The better way is sending an aggregation function to your counterpart and receiving already aggregated (and properly typed) data instead.

Answer (score 5):

You want to use the [`Numeric`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/math/Numeric.html) - [**typeclass**](https://tpolecat.github.io/2013/10/12/typeclass.html).

```
def sumGenList[T : Numeric](value: List[List[T]]): List[T] =
  value.map(_.sum)
```